# sh - split string by delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, sh, herestring

## code

```
s='id;some text here with possible ; inside'
IFS=';' read -r id string <<< "$s"
echo "$id"
```

## error

```
restore.sh: 2: restore.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

bash version `GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Working to me on `GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be using `sh` to execute the script.  Herestrings aren't supported in `sh`; hence the error.

Ensure that you're using `bash` to execute the script.

Comment: what is the difference between sh and bash?

Comment: @clarkk [Difference between sh and bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: Some Linux distributions use `dash` (not `bash`) as the shell that implements `sh`. `dash` is (mostly?) limited to the features specified by the POSIX specification, without the extra features like `<<<` implemented by `bash`.

Comment: how can I then do this operation with `sh`?

Comment: @clarkk Right; as mentioned in the answer herestrings aren't supported in `sh`.

Comment: @clarkk Maybe you could use `cut`.  `echo "$s" | cut -d; -f1` would return the first field.

Comment: this works `echo "$s" | cut -d";" -f1` but how can I assign it into a variable?

Comment: @clarkk: Use  `var=$(echo "$s" | cut -d";" -f1)`

Answer (score 11):

A here string is just a shortcut for a small here document. This should work in any POSIX shell:

```
string='id;some text here with possible ; inside'
IFS=';' read -r id string <<EOF
$string
EOF
echo "$id"
```

Comment: Am new to shell but from Java background. Can you explain your code ?

Comment: @Jess: very late comment but anyway, my two cents: POSIX `read` expects a line on standard input, reads that and splits it using $IFS contents as a separator, then assigns each chunk to variables given as arguments to `read` (`id` and `string`; `id` getting the first chunk and `string` getting all the remaining chunks). The trick with the two EOFs is called a "heredoc" and AFAIK is the only way to send that string to `read`'s standard input. See also https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html.

Answer (score 1):

save it in file split

```
#!/bin/sh

string=$1
c=0

while [ $c -le $3 ] 
do

val1=`echo "$string" |sed 's/\(^[^'$2']*\)\('$2'\+\)\(.*$\)/\1/'`
string=`echo "$string" |sed 's/\(^[^'$2']*\)\('$2'\+\)\(.*$\)/\3/'`

if [ "$val1" == "$string" ]
then
string=''
fi

if [ "$val1" == "" ]
then
let c=$3
fi

let c=c+1

done

echo $val1
```

and it work:

```
root@IPHONE:~# ./split 'a;b;c' ';' 0
a
root@IPHONE:~# ./split 'a/b/c' '\/' 0
a
root@IPHONE:~# ./split 'a/b/c' '\/' 2
c
root@IPHONE:~# ./split 'a/b/c' '\/' 1
b
```

Answer (score 0):

My result:

```
[root@localhost ~]# bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i686-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[root@localhost ~]# ./bash
id
[root@localhost ~]# cat bash
s='id;some text here with possible ; inside'
IFS=';' read -r id string <<< "$s"
echo "$id"
```

Worked here.

Answer (score -1):

I have used `python2.7` below:

```
#!/bin/sh

s='id;some text here with possible ; inside'
python -c "ifc, s =';', '$s';print s.split(';')[0] if ifc in s else ''"
```

Result:

```
 $ ./test.sh
id
```